# Area of the circle sector

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

Take the points $A(1, 5)$, $B(4, 4)$ and $C(-3, -3)$.
All of them belong to a circumference, which center is $M$.

Consider the circle that fits perfectly inside that circumference.

Calculate the area of the circle sector restricted between the points $A$, $M$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Pythagoran theorem the point $(1,0)$ has distance $5$ from $A,B,C$, hence it is the circumcenter of $ABC$. Once we have  $M=(1,0)$ the area of the circle sector delimited by $A,M,B$ can be computed as follows:

$$ \frac{\widehat{AMB}}{2\pi}\cdot \pi 5^2 $$
since the circumradius is $5$.
 We have $\widehat{AMB}=\arctan\frac{3}{4}$ hence the wanted area is $\approx \color{red}{8.04376386}$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Why is $AMB = arctan (3/4)$?

Comment: @MomotoSuarez: you are welcome. If this answer fits your needs, please take into consideration to upvote it and/or accept it as soon as you have enough reputation.

Comment: @MomotoSuarez: because $\widehat{AMB}$ is an angle in a (right) triangle with side lengths $3,4,5$. Can you find it in the picture? Just project $B$ on $MA$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the points of a circle with a center at $(x_c, y_c)$ and radius $r$ satisfies the equation $(x-x_c)^2 + (y-y_c)^2 = r^2$. As we know three points on the circle, we can produce three simultenous equations with three unknowns.
$$(1-x_c)^2+(5-y_c)^2 = r^2$$
$$(4-x_c)^2+(4-y_c)^2 = r^2$$
$$(-3-x_c)^2+(-3-y_c)^2 = r^2$$
Solving these eqautions yields $x_c=1$, $y_c=0$, $r=5$. The vector $\vec{MA}$ pointing from the center $M(1, 0)$ to $A(1, 5)$ is ${ 0 \choose 5}$, vector $\vec{MB}$ is ${3 \choose 4}$. The angle $\theta$ between these vectors can be determined using their vector product.
$$ \vec{MA}\cdot\vec{MB}=0\cdot3 + 5\cdot4 = \sqrt{0^2+5^2}\cdot\sqrt{3^2+4^2}\cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$ 20 = 25\cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$\theta= arccos\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$$
Now we can just use the formula for the area $A$ of a circular sector with  radius $r$ and central angle $\theta$.
$$A=\frac{r^2\theta}{2}$$
$$A=\frac{5^2\cdot\arccos\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}{2}\approx8.04$$

Comment: You have an error:  $M$ is the point (1,0), not (0,1).  This means that your calculation for $\theta$ is off.  Other than this, the method is correct.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I couldn't choose 2 best answers. Hope you understand it.